# Unknown file extension, nothing helps. Help please?

Tags: file-extension, file-types

All i know it is some kind of texture files, either contains textures of layers of something.
Nothing can open it, identifiers say it's .abr but none of the Photoshop versions could open it. Not CS2,CS3, CC2019
What is it and how to open it?
https://ufile.io/y7wne88q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Photoshop brush file, but is probably some invention of the
game or a corrupted file.

The header of this file is this :

[image]

But an
[Adobe post](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/reading-writing-and-previewing-abr-files-brushes-how/m-p/8536998)
describes the format of an `.abr` file as :

> - A brush file starts with a header: version (2-byte big-endian integer) followed by sub-version (2-byte big-endian integer).
> - After the header lies a sequence of sections organized by key: 'samp', 'patt' and 'desc' (I'm not sure if their order is fixed
>   though).
>
>   Each of them follows the same structure:
>
>   - Photoshop resource signature ('8BIM')
>   - 4-character key ('samp' or 'patt' or 'desc')
>   - length of data (4-byte big-endian integer)
>   - data (variable size)

As you can see, the file starts with two bytes of zero instead of
a version. I have also searched the entire file and haven't found the
signature string of "8BIM".

I have no idea what this file is, perhaps a proprietary format of that game.

Comment: Thanks you have looked into it anyway!

Answer (score 2):

An *.abr file is most likely a Photoshop Brush file. You cannot open it in Photoshop like you would open an image. You have to use the "Import Brushes" option in the Brushes palette.

Comment: Tried to import brush, DIdn't help.
"Not compatible with this version of Photoshop, hence why I said I tried it on CS2, CS3.
The files was made in 2007

Comment: File extensions are mostly pointless - but running the file against trid https://mark0.net/onlinetrid.py confirms its a photoshop brush. I wonder if they were running an older version than either.

Comment: Triet with CS1 original PS, same error message.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the file is simply corrupted, not that there's a version mismatch.

Comment: I doubt it, I have 500 hundred of these files, from a working game. There are sound files too without extension that plays in VLC. Nothing that points towards to corruption.

Comment: Ah, then... they're not Photoshop Brushes. They're something used by that game, *probably* something proprietary. You might get a clue if you look at a hex dump of the file; some binary files put an identifier in the first few bytes of the file.